# convert one specific query from text field to date for arithmetic functions

Tags: mysql, date

I have thoroughly searched but have been just as thoroughly confused at how to convert a returned SQL query into fields. I've found how to convert a whole column from text field into date but not a specific query. I'm not sure how to update, set, etc. I imported a CSV file of names and ates, and the query (in phpMyAdmin) that returns my desired text field is this:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `drabble_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'date_paid'
```

This returns roughly 130 fields that I need to convert from a pure text field that is uniformly using MM/DD/YYYY (ie 11/2/2010) format to actually using the "date" field so I can then sort by date_paid.

One `meta_value` I get has a text field with "11/2/2010". `meta_value` is longtext. I don't know if I want to use the AS operator because I'll need to read other `meta_value` fields where the id of those columns == the id of where I found the `date_paid`.

Comment: what type does meta_value have ? allso please post one meta_value you get from you're query , otherwise nobody will know what to convert .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%m/%d/%Y') AS date_paid
    FROM `drabble_postmeta` 
    WHERE meta_key = 'date_paid'
```

Comment: I get a syntax error using this, "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE meta_key = 'date_paid'' at line 3"